# Creating an autoupdate for my program and its database

Tags: database, windows, windows-installer, auto-update

I've already an offline updater as a download but I want to make it automatically. It's a client/server software and a ms sql database.

3 parts have to be updated:

1. update of a proprietary software (setup.exe with next, next, type login/password for server service, finish) which delivers a WinClient and a Service for the server. Autoupdate is only needed for server, the autoupdate for clients by the server works already.
2. one .hug file which contains new customized program version. The path is a directory in the above software and can be determined with registry.
3. MS SQL database update with new content (in a .bak file) and structural changes. The database server is sometimes another server as application server. At the moment you have to type in the SQL instance when running the udpater.

My ideas are these:

- a updater program in the tray on application server and database server
- updater searches with a timer for newer versions on my ftp server and downloads the files if existing
- on application server it runs the setup.exe and copies the .hug file. Maybe I could make it silent with command prompt commands. But still need to fill in login/password for the service user.
- on database server I configure the autoupdater once with instance name. Updater downloads .bak-file and runs sql script with insert, update and alter statements.
- but one big problem which can cause problems is when users are still logged in. Don't know in the moment how I could solve that.

So, how would you realise such a project? Or have you already done something similiar? Is its generally possible?

Comment: Do any of these files actually get installed with a Windows Installer MSI file? I ask because updating MSI-installed files requires an MSI-based update (such as msp patch, major upgrade etc). You can't simply replace files that need changing when they are managed by Windows Installer.

Comment: yes, the mentioned setup.exe in 1.consinsts of different msi files. Either I would run simply setup.exe and the user has to go through the setup manually or I could run the msi files automatically with command prompt commands. But one msi package needs login credentials, so I'm not sure at the moment which way I will choose.

Comment: Just be wary of the issue - updates that are not MSI-based can cause issues, so better to download msp .patches or major upgrades.